# Draggable clone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

drag drop example.
cloning disabled
[source](http://jsbin.com/oduxex/3/edit)
I need cloning codes

```
      .parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
                    revert  : 'invalid'
                    ,helper:'clone'// I added this line
                });
```

What necessary changes?
I'd appreciate if you look at the source code

Answer (score 0):

Changing the two lines to

```
revert  : "invalid", // note the double quotes
helper : "clone"// I added this line
```

made it work for me in your example.

Comment: This is not the solution.
Drag and drop already exists. only needs to be added cloning.
the dragged item is added to the right panel

Comment: @Kasva Exactly, when I changed it to clone with double quotes, i could see the initial image in place and a dragged element as well.

Comment: @Kasva And I noticed that you have this draggable declaration at two places. Make sure to correct it at both

Comment: yes. in the background div and left sidebar. 
http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/
I want this clone technique

Comment: @Kasva I did not understand this bit. For your initial problem, adding the helper: clone as per answer worked for me in your jsbin. Did you modify your code for that and check ? Next, what do you mean by I want this clone technique

Comment: I tried but did not work. I think a few code changes are necessary. jsbin worked correctly, right?

Comment: Yes it worked for me. On IE 8.  So i suggest look through your script and check for any other script errors

Comment: resolved in less than
http://jsbin.com/oduxex/11/edit

problem 1: cloned item draggable and resize
problem 2: drop possition